# Prove boundary of an open ball in $\mathbb{R^n}$ directly from definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to prove that the boundary of the open ball $B(a,\delta)=\{x \in \mathbb{R^n} : ||x-a||<\delta\}$ is the set $S(a,\delta)=\{x \in \mathbb{R^n} : ||x-a||=\delta\}$. I know there are other threads that discuss this topic but they all provide the answer recurring to other topological concepts such as the closure. In my case, I wanna prove it showing that every open ball centered in $x \in S(a,\delta)$ verifies that its intersection with $B(a,\delta)$ is non-empty and its intersection with $B(a,\delta)^C$ is also non-empty.

My attempt for the first non-empty intersection: If $x \in S(a,\delta)$, then $||x-a||=\delta$ and for every open ball $B(x,r)=\{y \in \mathbb{R^n}:||x-y||<r\}$, we need to show that $y \in B(a, \delta)$, that is to say, $||y-a||<\delta$. Then I have seen that, using the triangle inequality, $||y-a|| \leq ||x-a||+ ||y-x|| \leq \delta+r$ but this doesn't prove what I need.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: that is not what you need to show. you need to show the existence of a point $y\in B(x,r)\cap B(a,\delta)$ and a point $y’\in B(x,r)\cap B(a,\delta)^C$. if you draw this out, it should be clear what to do. hint: consider the line passing through $x$ and the origin.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was trying to express I needed to prove those two existances but I got confused. But I don't really have a clue to find out those $y$ and $y'$. If I were in $\mathbb{R}$, I would try to take $\frac{r}{2}$ but that's not possible here. Could you please elaborate a bit more your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Fix open ball $B(a, \delta)$. Choose point on the sphere of the same radius $x \in S(a, \delta)$ and any positive $r > 0$. We want to prove that
$$
B(a, \delta) \cap B(x, r) \neq \emptyset, \quad
B(a, \delta)^c \cap B(x, r) \neq \emptyset.
$$
Second one is trivial: we have $x \not \in B(a, \delta)$, so $x \in B(a, \delta)^c \cap B(x, r)$ and the set is not empty.

For the first one consider line segment passing through $a$ and $x$, that is
$$
L = \{\lambda a + (1-\lambda)x : \lambda \in [0, 1]\}.
$$
Pick point $y\in L$ to correspond to lambda value of
$$
\lambda = \frac{\min\left\{\frac r 2, \frac \delta 2\right \}}  \delta.
$$
Note that $0<\lambda \leq 1/2$. We have
$$\|x - y\|=\|\lambda x-\lambda a\|=\lambda \delta < r,$$
and
$$
\|a - y\|=\|(1-\lambda) a-(1-\lambda) x\| = (1 - \lambda)\delta < \delta,
$$
so $y \in B(a, \delta) \cap B(x, r)\quad \square$

---

**Note:** the above proves that $S(a, \delta) \subseteq \partial B(a, \delta) $.

To show equality you need to know that open ball is open, and the set $\{x \in \mathbb R^n: \|x - a\| > \delta\}$ is open as well.

Comment: Thank you so much @Esgeriath! Understood it. This process could be applied, in general, to prove the boundary of a set of this kind, right?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean by "set of this kind". I think it should work for finite sum of star domains, if you get them defined in a way that for given direction and star-center point tells distance for which all closer points belong to the set.

Comment: Alright, thanks again for your time!